# opencv: Conversion from RGB to grayscale getting only blue

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I'm trying to convert some RGB color images to greyscale using OpenCV with C++ but the only thing I can get is a blue scale image.
[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5bGv.jpg)
["Converted"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xEy3.png)

```
Vec3b simpleAveraging(Vec3b color){
    Vec3b gray = ((float)color[0] + (float)color[1] + (float)color[2]) / 3.0;

    return gray;
}

Vec3b weightedAverage1(Vec3b color){
    Vec3b gray = 0.3 * (float)color[2] + 0.59 * (float)color[1] + 0.11 * (float)color[0];

    return gray;
}

Vec3b weightedAverage2(Vec3b color){
    Vec3b gray = 0.2126 * (float)color[2] + 0.7152 * (float)color[1] + 0.0722 * (float)color[0];

    return gray;
}

Vec3b weightedAverage3(Vec3b color){
    Vec3b gray = 0.299 * (float)color[2] + 0.587 * (float)color[1] + 0.114 * (float)color[0];

    return gray;
}

...

for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    for(int y = 0; y < img[i].rows; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < img[i].cols; x++){
            color = img[i].at<Vec3b>(Point(x, y));

            img[i].at<Vec3b>(Point(x, y)) = weightedAverage3(color);
        }
    }
}
```

It is for a university project and my professor told me to use these algorithms so I can't use CV_RGB2GRAY.
I get the blue scale with every method.

Comment: Either set img type to CV_8UC1 (grayscale) or set all 3 channels of your initial 3channel image to weightedAverage3(color). Right now you are only setting first channel which is blue.

Comment: Grayscale images consist of only single channel, so returning a `cv::Vec3b` doesn't make sense, it ought to be a `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have only 3 channels ?

Anyway in that case:

```
uint8_t weightedAverage3(Vec3b color){
    uint8_t gray = 0.301 * (float)color[0] + 0.587 * (float)color[1] + 0.114 * (float)color[2];

    return gray;
}

for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    for(int y = 0; y < img[i].rows; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < img[i].cols; x++){
            color = img[i].at<Vec3b>(Point(x, y));

            img[i].at<uchar>(Point(x, y)) = weightedAverage3(color);
        }
    }
}
```

assuming 0 is R, 1 is G and 2 is B.

Comment: This does not at all address OPs problem. Note that the right side of the equal sign here is a single value, while you've assigned that to a `Vec3b` and returned it as a `Vec3b`.

Comment: So this looks basically correct, but you're assigning a single `uchar` value for a three-channel image. Would be best to assign to a new single-channel `Mat` I think, no?